# Angular 2 *ngFor

Tags: angular

Here is my code:

> 

```
saveHierarchyData() {
    debugger;
    this.hierarchySwitch = 'currentHierarchies';
    this.topLevelArray.unshift(this.levelsArray);
  }

levelsArray[
{levelName: "",
 HierarchyName:  "",
 ConditonName: ""
}
]
```

I am pushing the 'levelsArray' to 'topLevelArray'. My HTML is

```
<li *ngFor="let hierarchies of topLevelArray" [@deleteAnim]>
              <div class="hierarchyName">
                <span>{{hierarchies.hierarchyName}}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="actionIcons">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteLevel(hierarchies)"></i>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Now, my problem is I need to display the 'HierarchyName' value in the span inside the 'li' above. Here is a screenshot of my console for 'topLevelArray' array:

[image]

How do I populate the hierarchyname value in the span element?

Comment: hierarchies[0].hierarchyName?

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my issue.

Comment: hierarchies.hierarchyName  vs  HierarchyName:  "", was that a typo ?

Comment: screenshot of your expected vs actual. if you can create a plunker that would be great

Comment: Yeah jmugz3, that was a typo.

Comment: Thank you Aravind for your time, the issue is resolved now.